# How to use JavaScript sentence cases in this case?

Tags: javascript

All around in the net I see just Title case, lower case and upper case in simplified situations.

I have a bit different problem...

"You are not the Intended recipient. YOU ARE NOT THE INTENDED RECIPIENT. YOU ARE NOT THE intended RECIPIENT."

I need to convert "intended" into "INTENDED" since the rest of the sentence is in upper case. And "Intended" into lower case since rest of the sentence is in lower case.

EDIT:
I need a general solution to this, where one determines the case of the sentence and normalize it. I need to use special characters like "ñ" or "ä" in my string.

I am using JavaScript *without* jQuery.

Comment: This might be my last question, since might suffer a question ban. I scrap the whole internet before posting here, in fear of the ban. Please help...

Comment: you can do `str = str.replace(/intended/g, "INTENDED")`

Comment: I can't you see... Else the first sentence will be affected.

Comment: Does your whole string contains only uppercase/lowercase or mixed case?

Comment: In your first sentence, `Intended` has a _captial_ `i`. In your second sentence, it has a lowercase `i`. So it will only change the one in the second sentence

Comment: I am seeking for a code to identify the case in the sentence then do the rest accordingly...

Comment: @Justinas Mixed

Comment: use normalization..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume your whole string contains only uppercase or lowercase you can do something like that.

Is not the perfect solution but it's can give you idea :

```
var upper = "YOU ARE NOT THE INTENDED RECIPIENT. YOU ARE NOT THE intended RECIPIENT";
var lower = "you are not the intended recipient. you are not the INTENDED recipient";

function normalize(sentence) {
    if (sentence[0] === sentence[0].toUpperCase()) {
        return sentence.toUpperCase();
    }
    if (sentence[0] === sentence[0].toLowerCase()) {
        return sentence.toLowerCase();
    }
}

console.log(normalize(upper));
console.log(normalize(lower));
```

which returns

```
YOU ARE NOT THE INTENDED RECIPIENT. YOU ARE NOT THE INTENDED RECIPIENT
you are not the intended recipient. you are not the intended recipient
```

Comment: What could be a general solution? You maked the sentences with the startsWith(). It is undermining the case of the sentence. Can you generalise it for all alphabet?

Comment: I think my work is done if sentence[1] is used. Since every sentence begin with an upper case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = "You are not the Intended recipient.";
var str2 = "YOU ARE NOT THE intended RECIPIENT.";

function convert(str) {
  var flag = str.startsWith('You') || str.startsWith('you')
  if(flag) {
  // If starting with You return You else return you
    return str.substring(0,3) + str.substring(3).toLowerCase();
  } else {
    return str.toUpperCase();
  }

}

console.log(convert(str1));
console.log(convert(str2));
```